# When you record a video at 60 fps, how can you play the video back at 24 fps?

Tags: video, media-player, editing

I saw a friend shooting video at 60 fps and then playing the videos back at 24 fps. Seeing the 60 fps video playback at 24 fps was quite amazing and impressive (dramatic almost slow motion effect)!

He did all of this on what looked like an expensive DLSR device.

My question is:

**When you record a video at 60 fps, how can you play the video back at 24 fps?**

I tried to edit the video on my pixel 2 but there wasn't anything there for changing the fps. Maybe I will try VLC player.

Answer (score 5):

Using VLC player:

- play the video
- tap the screen to bring up the controls
- click the three dots button
- click the"playback speed" button
- adjust to 45 - 50%
- done

It doesn't get you exactly the 24 fps but it's something!

I would love to have a way to export the video at 24fps. Or better video editing for built-in Android apps.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [Cyberlink Power Director](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyberlink.powerdirector.DRA140225_01&hl=en) on Android for doing this, you need to slow it down to around %45 and then export the video at 24 FPS

Export Steps with Power Director

1 - Select Save Video
[image: step 1]

2 - Select Save to Device
[image: step 2]

3 - Select Options
[image: options]

4 - Select Frame rate
[image: framerate]

5 - Select 24FPS
[image: 24]

6 - Optional Bit rate
[image: bits]

7 - Save
 [image]

8 - Export
[image: port]

Comment: Awesome screen capture

Answer (score 1):

Frames get dropped, carried over as required. In effect the 60FPS is "strobed" to 24FPS. This is a common topic for home cinema buffs as 24FPS is a standard.

You need to transcode, an android device is not the best for this. 
Search for `Video Transcoder`, maybe have a look at [Timbre](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xeus.timbre).

Most people would upload to a workstation for anything serious or large.

Comment: Agreed, a workstation is ideal for large videos but Android device's seem to handle 30minute video exports at FullHD, and 4K fairly easily.